# Is Freight Train hopping possible in South-America?

Tags: trains, south-america

Has anyone ever done it? Do you know anything about the cargo-train system in those countrys? Im not looking for specific countrys. I couldnt find anything about that in south-america. only usa.

Comment: Good question IMHO but you could be more specific as to which countries you are looking at? And have you done some own research on that?

Comment: Train hopping is one of the very dangerous 'methods of travel' and illegal in many countries. And for good reasons.

Comment: What do you mean by "possible"? It's obviously _possible_. Are you asking if it's legal? Practical? Safe?

Comment: Doing a Google web search for "railroad travel in south america" led to some useful sites... given that South America is a _huge_ continent, with many countries, I would generally have to agree with the VtC as Too Broad